# Tag excerpts are not [cute] definitions

Tags: discussion, tags, editing

*Preface: I'm not calling anyone out, just providing examples. It seems to me the first edit notice was not read, hence this post, which hopefully will also help others.*

Tag excerpts are not meant to be just definitions, or cute definitions. So kindly if you will suggest an edit, make sure it is professional, so the reviewers don't have to do all the work. Make sure it's about the usage.

Two examples I recently rejected and edited:

> ✘ [obstacle-clearance](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/obstacle-clearance) Questions about the art of staying high enough to keep from running into things sticking up from the ground, and the procedures used to accomplish this.
>
> ✔ [obstacle-clearance](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/obstacle-clearance) For questions on obstacle clearance, whether en route or on a procedure (departure and arrival), including the operational and regulatory aspects.

and

> ✘ [pilot-fatigue](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pilot-fatigue) Questions about sleepy pilots and the procedures put in place to keep them out of the cockpit.
>
> ✔ [pilot-fatigue](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pilot-fatigue) For questions on pilot fatigue, and the associated risk management and regulations.

For more guidance, please see: https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/03/24/redesigned-tags-page/ In particular:

> - Avoid generically defining the concept behind a tag, unless it is highly specialized
> - Concentrate on what a tag means to your community
> - Provide basic guidance on when to use the tag

Comment: I'm guessing Aviation doesn't have the same tag excerpt rejection reason SO does: **lacks usage guidance** Simply defining what a [tag] is rarely helps those using it unless the tag's name itself is ambiguous. Excerpts should describe why and when a tag should be used. [See the help center](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/tag-excerpts) for more guidance.

Comment: Agreed on the idea of not using "cute" definitions, but I would also suggest that using a formulaic `For questions on X` for some tag "X" is unhelpful; it seems redundant to say that tags go with questions about their respective subjects.

Comment: The excerpts in the OP with ticks are standard formulation for a reason, the tag text does not always match up perfectly with the subject of the tag, or may have additional synonyms that are preferred in some contexts but where one has been chosen as the primary term on SE for consistency purposes.